# How to drag using Selenium webdriver 3 where the underlying element to drag from is an <img> tag

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am using Selenium 3 with Java, Cucumber & ChromeDriver . I am trying to drag from an img element but Selenium does not allow to shift the focus to that element in order to drag and drop. I have tried all the below options. Pls. let me know if anyone can help.

Using Keyboard Actions:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(someElement).click(someOtherElement).        keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Using Mouse Actions:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(someElement).moveToElement(otherElement).release( otherElement).build().perform();
```

Code Works fine with Robot class :

```
public String dragElementFrom="//div[@class='asset-instructions col-xs-6']/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]/div/img";
public String dragElementTo="//*[@id='parity-on-page-preview']";
```

WebElement e=objHelp.WaitForElement(driver,By.xpath(obj.dragElementFrom));
   WebElement f=objHelp.WaitForElement(driver,By.xpath(obj.dragElementTo));

```
 Point coordinates1 = e.getLocation();
 Point coordinates2 = f.getLocation();
 Robot robot = new Robot();

 robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX()+55, coordinates1.getY()+118);
 robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX()+200, coordinates2.getY()+200);
 robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 Thread.sleep(2000);
```

The problem with robot class is when i run the test, I need to ensure that the browser window is focused else Robot class doesn't work.

I have tried using Firefox also but its the same. Also I did research stackoverflow but could not find my answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly Selenium 3 does not support HTML 5 drag and drop. They are working on it: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285
There are javascript based solutions but they don't always work.